# Delete multiple nodes from a binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree created in C. The problem is I can't find a efficient way to delete all the nodes with e.g., id>5.

When I traverse the tree, if I delete a node, the recursion is getting error, because the structure is not the same.

Is there any way, instead of using a helping stack to keep the data before delete them from the tree?

Comment: I don't understand why a binary search tree would have duplicate IDs; assuming you are using the ID as the search key.

Comment: I am not having the same IDs. I am trying to delete all the IDs (or timestamps) that are bigger than some value e.g. 5!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try postorder?
Delete the node after its children.

Comment: I was trying to do it with in-order traversing. Using the post-order, I fixed my problem. Thanks for the remind!

Answer (score 1):

Kostas. You need to give more information.

A binary tree just means a tree whose nodes have (a maximum of) two children.  Data can be ordered many ways on such a tree:

- Unordered: There is no relationship between a parent and its nodes.
- Heap: A node is bigger than (or smaller than) all of its children
- Ordered: One child is  designated *smaller* and the other *larger*.  All values smaller than the root are to one side, all values larger to the other.

If you give us code, we might be able to help more.

Comment: it does say *"binary search tree"*.

Comment: The insert adds only leaves (something like this http://bit.ly/89hJma). The way I am searching is:
while (curr != NULL) {
   prev = curr;
   if (id < curr->id)
      curr = curr->lc;
   else
      curr = curr->rc;
}
and then, if the id is smaller I add it as left child of prev, else as right child.

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer the AVL tree for this satuation.

here is the code take what you want

```
class BSTree
 {


/*     */   public static final int INSERT = 1;

/*     */   public static final int DELETE = -1;

/*     */   BTNode root;

/*     */   boolean AVL;

/*     */   boolean SPL;

/*     */   boolean RBL;

/*     */   BTNode lastnode;

/*     */   int nextside;
/*     */ 

/*     */   public BSTree(int mode)
/*     */   {
/*  18 */     this.root = null;

/*  19 */     setMode(mode, true);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public void setMode(int mode, boolean state) {

/*  23 */     switch (mode)

/*     */     {

/*     */     case 1:

/*  26 */       if (state == true)

/*     */       {

/*  28 */         this.AVL = true;

/*  29 */         this.SPL = false;

/*  30 */         this.RBL = false;

/*     */ 
/*  26 */         return;


/*     */       }

/*     */ 
/*  33 */       this.AVL = false;

/*  34 */       break;


/*     */     case 2:

/*  37 */       if (state == true)

/*     */       {

/*  39 */         this.SPL = true;

/*  40 */         this.AVL = false;

/*  41 */         this.RBL = false;

/*     */ 
/*  37 */         return;

/*     */       }
/*     */ 

/*  44 */       this.SPL = false;

/*  45 */       break;

/*     */     case 3:

/*  48 */       if (state == true)

/*     */       {

/*  50 */         this.RBL = true;

/*  51 */         this.AVL = false;

/*  52 */         this.SPL = false;

/*     */ 
/*  48 */         return;


/*     */       }

/*     */ 
/*  55 */       this.RBL = false;


/*  56 */       break;

/*     */     default:


/*  59 */       this.AVL = false;

/*  60 */       this.SPL = false;

/*  61 */       this.RBL = false;

/*     */     }

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public boolean isAVL() {

/*  66 */     return this.AVL;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public boolean isSPL() {

/*  70 */     return this.SPL;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public boolean isRBL() {

/*  74 */     return this.RBL;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode getRoot()

/*     */   {

/*  79 */     return this.root;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public void setRoot(BTNode node) {

/*  83 */     this.root = node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public boolean isEmpty() {

/*  87 */     return (this.root == null);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public int getDepth()

/*     */   {

/*  92 */     int maxdepth = 0;

/*  93 */     for (BTNode node = this.root; node != null; node = node.nextPrO())

/*     */     {

/*  95 */       int depth = node.getDepth(this.root);


/*  96 */       if (depth > maxdepth)

/*  97 */         maxdepth = depth;

/*     */     }

/*  99 */     return maxdepth;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public void destroy(BTNode node)

/*     */   {

/* 104 */     node = null;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode find(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 113 */     BTNode node = locate(data);


/* 114 */     if (isSPL())



/* 115 */       splay(this.lastnode);

/* 116 */     return node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode insert(BTData data) {

/* 120 */     if (isSPL()) {

/* 121 */       return insertSPL(data);

/*     */     }

/* 123 */     if (isAVL()) {

/* 124 */       return insertAVL(data);

/*     */     }

/* 126 */     if (isRBL()) {

/* 127 */       return insertRBL(data);

/*     */     }

/* 129 */     return insertBST(data);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode delete(BTData data, int minmax) {

/* 133 */     if (isAVL()) {

/* 134 */       return deleteAVL(data, minmax);

/*     */     }

/* 136 */     if (isSPL()) {

/* 137 */       return deleteSPL(data, minmax);

/*     */     }

/* 139 */     if (isRBL()) {

/* 140 */       return deleteRBL(data, minmax);

/*     */     }

/* 142 */     return deleteBST(data, minmax);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode locate(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 150 */     BTNode node = this.root;

/* 151 */     BTNode next = null;

/* 152 */     int side = 0;
/*     */ 

/* 154 */     while (node != null)

/*     */     {

/* 156 */       side = node.compareSide(data);

/* 157 */       next = node.getChild(side);


/* 158 */       if (next == node) break; if (next == null)
/*     */         break;


/* 160 */       node = next;

/*     */     }

/* 162 */     this.lastnode = node;

/* 163 */     this.nextside = side;

/* 164 */     return next;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode add(BTNode node, int side, BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 170 */     BTNode newnode = new BTNode(data);

/* 171 */     link(node, side, newnode);

/* 172 */     return newnode;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode remove(BTNode node)

/*     */   {

/* 181 */     BTNode child = node.getChild();

/* 182 */     BTNode parent = node.getParent();

/* 183 */     int side = node.getSide();

/* 184 */     link(parent, side, child);

/* 185 */     destroy(node);

/* 186 */     return parent;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public void link(BTNode parent, int side, BTNode child)

/*     */   {

/* 193 */     if (child != null)

/* 194 */       child.setParent(parent);

/* 195 */     if (parent != null)

/* 196 */       parent.setChild(side, child);

/*     */     else

/* 198 */       this.root = child;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode rotate(BTNode node, int side)


/*     */   {

/* 206 */     BTNode parent = node.getParent();

/* 207 */     BTNode child = node.getChild(-side);

/* 208 */     BTNode grand = child.getChild(side);


/*     */ 
/* 210 */     link(node, -side, grand);

/* 211 */     link(parent, node.getSide(), child);

/* 212 */     link(child, side, node);

/* 213 */     return child;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode swap(BTNode node, int minmax)

/*     */   {

/* 222 */     BTNode swap = getSuccessor(node, minmax);



/* 223 */     BTNode temp = node;

/* 224 */     swapData(node, swap);

/* 225 */     node = swap;

/* 226 */     swap = temp;

/* 227 */     return node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode getSuccessor(BTNode node, int minmax) {

/* 231 */     return ((minmax == 1) ? node.prevInO() : node.nextInO());

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public void swapData(BTNode node1, BTNode node2)

/*     */   {
/* 237 */     BTData data = node1.getData();

/* 238 */     node1.setData(node2.getData());

/* 239 */     node2.setData(data);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public void deleteAll()

/*     */   {

/* 245 */     for (BTNode node = this.root.firstPoO(); node != null; )

/*     */     {
/* 247 */       BTNode leaf = node;

/* 248 */       node = leaf.nextPoO();

/* 249 */       destroy(leaf);

/*     */     }

/* 251 */     this.root = null;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode locateBST(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 260 */     for (BTNode node = this.root; node != null; )

/*     */     {
/* 262 */       int side = node.compareSide(data);


/* 263 */       if (side == 0)
/*     */         break;

/* 265 */       node = node.getChild(side);

/*     */     }

/* 267 */     return node;

/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public BTNode insertBST(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 272 */     if (this.root == null)

/* 273 */       return add(null, 0, data);




/* 274 */     BTNode node = locate(data);



/* 275 */     return ((node != null) ? null : add(this.lastnode, this.nextside, data));



/*     */   }



/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode deleteBST(BTData data, int minmax)


/*     */   {





/* 280 */     BTNode node = locate(data);



/* 281 */     if (node == null)

/* 282 */       return null;

/* 283 */     if (node.hasTwoChildren())

/* 284 */       node = swap(node, minmax);

/* 285 */     return remove(node);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode insertAVL(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 297 */     if (this.root == null)

/* 298 */       return add(null, 0, data);

/* 299 */     if (locate(data) != null)


/* 300 */       return null;

/* 301 */     BTNode node = add(this.lastnode, this.nextside, data);

/* 302 */     rebalanceAVL(this.lastnode, this.nextside, 1);

/* 303 */     return node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 


/*     */   public BTNode deleteAVL(BTData data, int minmax)

/*     */   {

/* 315 */     BTNode node = locate(data);

/* 316 */     if (node == null) {

/* 317 */       return null;

/*     */     }


/* 319 */     if (node.hasTwoChildren()) {

/* 320 */       node = swap(node, minmax);


/*     */     }

/* 322 */     int side = node.getSide();

/* 323 */     node = remove(node);

/* 324 */     rebalanceAVL(node, side, -1);


/* 325 */     return node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public void rebalanceAVL(BTNode node, int side, int in)

/*     */   {

/* 333 */     for (; node != null; node = node.getParent())

/*     */     {

/* 335 */       if (node.getBalance() != in * side)

/* 336 */         node.setBalance(node.getBalance() + in * side);

/*     */       else {

/* 338 */         node = rotateAVL(node);

/*     */       }

/* 340 */       if ((in == 1) && (node.getBalance() == 0)) return; if ((in == -1) && 

(node.getBalance() != 0))

/*     */         return;

/* 342 */       side = node.getSide();


/*     */     }

/*     */   }


/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode rotateAVL(BTNode node)


/*     */   {

/* 357 */     int side = node.getBalance();

/* 358 */     BTNode child = node.getChild(side);

/*     */ 

/* 360 */     if (child.getBalance() == -side)

/*     */     {

/* 362 */       BTNode grand = child.getChild(-side);

/* 363 */       if (grand.getBalance() == -side)

/*     */       {

/* 365 */         grand.setBalance(0);

/* 366 */         child.setBalance(side);

/* 367 */         node.setBalance(0);

/*     */       }

/* 369 */       else if (grand.getBalance() == side)

/*     */       {

/* 371 */         grand.setBalance(0);

/* 372 */         child.setBalance(0);

/* 373 */         node.setBalance(-side);

/*     */       }

/*     */       else {

/* 376 */         node.setBalance(0);

/* 377 */         child.setBalance(0);

/*     */       }

/* 379 */       rotate(child, side);

/*     */     }

/* 382 */     else if (child.getBalance() == side)

/*     */     {

/* 384 */       node.setBalance(0);

/* 385 */       child.setBalance(0);

/*     */     }

/* 387 */     else if (child.getBalance() == 0)

/*     */     {

/* 389 */       node.setBalance(side);

/* 390 */       child.setBalance(-side);

/*     */     }

/* 392 */     node = rotate(node, -side);

/* 393 */     return node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public void balanceAVL(BTNode node)

/*     */   {

/* 400 */     int side = node.getBalance();

/* 401 */     BTNode child = node.getChild(side);

/* 402 */     if (child.getBalance() == -side)

/*     */     {


/* 404 */       BTNode grand = child.getChild(-side);

/* 405 */       if (grand.getBalance() == -side)

/*     */       {

/* 407 */         grand.setBalance(0);

/* 408 */         child.setBalance(side);

/* 409 */         node.setBalance(0);



/*     */       }

/* 411 */       else if (grand.getBalance() == side)

/*     */       {

/* 413 */         grand.setBalance(0);

/* 414 */         child.setBalance(0);

/* 415 */         node.setBalance(-side);

/*     */       }

/*     */       else {

/* 418 */         node.setBalance(0);

/* 419 */         child.setBalance(0);

/*     */       }

/*     */ 

/*     */     }

/* 423 */     else if (child.getBalance() == side)

/*     */     {





/* 425 */       child.setBalance(0);

/* 426 */       node.setBalance(0);

/*     */     } else {

/* 428 */       if (child.getBalance() != 0)

/*     */         return;

/* 430 */       child.setBalance(-side);

/*     */     }

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public boolean isAVLcompliant(BTNode node)

/*     */   {

/* 440 */     boolean balanced = true;

/*     */ 

/* 442 */     if (node == null)

/* 443 */       return true;

/* 444 */     int l = getHeight(node.getChild(-1), 0);

/* 445 */     int r = getHeight(node.getChild(1), 0);


/* 446 */     node.setBalance(r - l);


/* 447 */     if ((r - l > 1) || (r - l < -1))


/* 448 */       balanced = false;


/* 449 */     return ((balanced) && (isAVLcompliant(node.getChild(-1))) && (isAVLcompliant

(node.getChild(1))));

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public int getHeight(BTNode node, int depth)

/*     */   {

/* 454 */     if (node == null)

/* 455 */       return 0;

/* 456 */     if (node.isLeaf()) {

/* 457 */       return (depth + 1);

/*     */     }

/*     */ 

/* 460 */     int lmax = getHeight(node.getChild(-1), depth + 1);

/* 461 */     int rmax = getHeight(node.getChild(1), depth + 1);

/* 462 */     return ((lmax > rmax) ? lmax : rmax);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode insertSPL(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 474 */     if (this.root == null)

/* 475 */       return add(null, 0, data);

/* 476 */     BTNode node = locate(data);


/* 477 */     splay(this.lastnode);

/* 478 */     return ((node != null) ? null : splitinsert(data));

/*     */   }


/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode splitinsert(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 483 */     BTNode node = new BTNode(data);

/* 484 */     int side = -this.root.compareSide(data);

/* 485 */     BTNode child = this.root.getChild(-side);

/*     */ 

/* 487 */     this.root.setChild(-side, null);

/* 488 */     link(node, side, this.root);

/* 489 */     link(node, -side, child);

/* 490 */     this.root = node;

/* 491 */     return this.root;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode deleteSPL(BTData data, int minmax)

/*     */   {

/* 498 */     BTNode node = locate(data);

/* 499 */     splay(this.lastnode);

/* 500 */     if (node == null)

/* 501 */       return null;

/* 502 */     BTNode root = node;

/* 503 */     node = getSuccessor(root, minmax);

/* 504 */     if (node != null)

/* 505 */       splay(node);

/* 506 */     return remove(root);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public void splay(BTNode node)

/*     */   {

/* 516 */     while (node != this.root)


/*     */     {

/* 518 */       BTNode parent = node.getParent();


/* 519 */       BTNode grandparent = parent.getParent();

/* 520 */       int side = node.getSide();

/* 521 */       if (grandparent == null) {

/* 522 */         rotate(parent, -side);

/*     */       }

/* 524 */       else if (parent.getSide() == side)

/*     */       {

/* 526 */         rotate(grandparent, -side);

/* 527 */         rotate(parent, -side);

/*     */       }

/*     */       else {

/* 530 */         if (parent.getSide() == side)

/*     */           continue;

/* 532 */         rotate(parent, -side);

/* 533 */         rotate(grandparent, side);

/*     */       }

/*     */     }

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public boolean isSPLcompliant()

/*     */   {



/* 541 */     return true;

/*     */   }


/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode insertRBL(BTData data)

/*     */   {

/* 552 */     if (this.root == null)

/*     */     {

/* 554 */       this.root = add(null, 0, data);

/* 555 */       this.root.setColor(2);

/* 556 */       return this.root;

/*     */     }

/* 558 */     if (locate(data) != null)

/* 559 */       return null;

/* 560 */     BTNode node = add(this.lastnode, this.nextside, data);

/* 561 */     node.setColor(1);

/* 562 */     fixRBinsert(node);

/* 563 */     return node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public void fixRBinsert(BTNode node)

/*     */   {

/* 571 */     while (node != this.root)
/*     */     {

/* 573 */       BTNode parent = node.getParent();

/* 574 */       if (parent.getColor() == 2)

/*     */         break;

/* 576 */       BTNode grandparent = parent.getParent();

/* 577 */       int side = parent.getSide();

/* 578 */       BTNode uncle = grandparent.getChild(-side);

/* 579 */       if ((uncle != null) && (uncle.getColor() == 1))

/*     */       {

/* 581 */         parent.setColor(2);

/* 582 */         uncle.setColor(2);

/* 583 */         grandparent.setColor(1);

/* 584 */         node = grandparent;

/*     */       }

/* 586 */       else if (node.getSide() == -side)

/*     */       {

/* 588 */         rotate(parent, side);

/* 589 */         node = parent;

/*     */       } else {

/* 591 */         if (node.getSide() != side)

/*     */           continue;

/* 593 */         parent.setColor(2);

/* 594 */         grandparent.setColor(1);

/* 595 */         rotate(grandparent, -side);

/*     */       }

/*     */     }

/* 598 */     this.root.setColor(2);


/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public BTNode deleteRBL(BTData data, int minmax)

/*     */   {

/* 606 */     BTNode node = locate(data);

/* 607 */     if (node == null) {

/* 608 */       return null;

/*     */     }

/* 610 */     if (node.hasTwoChildren()) {

/* 611 */       node = swap(node, minmax);

/*     */     }

/* 613 */     int color = node.getColor();

/* 614 */     int side = node.getSide();

/* 615 */     node = remove(node);

/* 616 */     if ((this.root != null) && (side == 0)) {

/* 617 */       this.root.setColor(2);

/*     */     }

/* 619 */     else if ((node != null) && (color == 2))

/* 620 */       fixRBdelete(node, side);

/* 621 */     return node;

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public void fixRBdelete(BTNode parent, int side)

/*     */   {

/* 629 */     BTNode node = parent.getChild(side);

/* 630 */     if ((node != null) && (node.getColor() == 1))

/*     */     {


/* 632 */       node.setColor(2);

/* 633 */       return;

/*     */     }

/*     */ 

/*     */     do

/*     */     {

/* 638 */       if (node != null)



/*     */       {

/* 640 */         parent = node.getParent();

/* 641 */         side = node.getSide();

/*     */       }

/* 643 */       BTNode sibling = parent.getChild(-side);

/* 644 */       BTNode nephew = sibling.getChild(side);

/* 645 */       BTNode niece = sibling.getChild(-side);

/*     */ 

/* 647 */       if (sibling.getColor() == 1)

/*     */       {

/* 649 */         sibling.setColor(2);

/* 650 */         parent.setColor(1);

/* 651 */         rotate(parent, side);

/*     */       }

/* 654 */       else if ((isBlack(nephew)) && (isBlack(niece)))

/*     */       {

/* 656 */         sibling.setColor(1);

/* 657 */         node = (node == null) ? parent : node.getParent();

/*     */       }


/* 660 */       else if ((isBlack(niece)) && (isRed(nephew)))



/*     */       {

/* 662 */         sibling.setColor(1);

/* 663 */         nephew.setColor(2);

/* 664 */         rotate(sibling, -side);

/*     */       }

/*     */       else {

/* 667 */         if (!(isRed(niece)))

/*     */           continue;

/* 669 */         sibling.setColor(parent.getColor());



/* 670 */         parent.setColor(2)
;
/* 671 */         niece.setColor(2);
/* 672 */
         rotate(parent, side);
/* 673 */ 
        node = this.root;
/*     */ 
      }
/*     */ 
    }
/* 636 */ 
    while ((node != this.root) && (isBlack(node)));
/*     */ 
/* 676 */     node.setColor(2);

/*     */   }

/*     */ 

/*     */   public boolean isRed(BTNode node)

/*     */   {



/* 681 */ 


    return ((node != null) && (node.getColor() == 1));
/*     */ 
  }
/*     */ 


/*     */   public boolean isBlack(BTNode node) {

/* 685 */ 

    return ((node == null) || (node.getColor() == 2));
/*     */ 
  }
/*     */ 

/*     */   public boolean isRBLcompliant(BTNode node)

/*     */   {

/* 690 */     return false;


/*     */   }

/*     */ }
```

this is full implementation. Best of luck.

Comment: No offense, but he's on C. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you navigate to the node and link its children with the node's parent so that you don't break the tree? The idea is to

- find the node
- save reference to its children
- save reference to its parent
- link parent to the node's children(s)
- only then remove the node (free)

As it is explained better on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion), you must be careful and determine how many children it has. After that it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: This algorithm can quickly turn the tree non-binary.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an inorder walk, this gives you an orderd list of all items. Then build the tree again.

Or if you need to do this often, maybe a [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) is better.